# "Diejenigen, die..." and phrases of this form -- collocations?

Tags: standard-german

Are phrases of the form "diejenigen, die..." (and "der," "das" with the according changes) inseparable?

I was under the assumption that they were until I saw this sentence on Quora:

> "Und da satteln **diejenigen** drauf **die** mit dieser Klientel selbst Profit machen wie Buchautoren und die bekannten Verlage."

After some searching, I found a couple others:

> "Nach einiger Zeit war es uns zu blöd und wir wollten mehr von dem süßen Teil der Erdbeere haben, also haben wir kontinuierlich **diejenigen** Erdbeeren weiter vermehrt **die** das größte Fruchtfleisch hatten."
>
> "Manchmal aber erholen sich **diejenigen** wieder und beginnen die Dogmen selbst zu hinterfragen."

Are these phrases different altogether from the formulaic one above?

Comment: Maybe my edit clarifies a bit why not all of these sentences are using _diejenigen ,,, die_.

Comment: There should be commas in front of the _die_ set in bold.

Answer (score 3):

when *die* acts as a relative pronoun, it's just a usual construction not dissimilar from

> Ich mag Erdbeeren, die süß sind.

you might find "diejenigen Erdbeeren, die süß sind" or "die Erdbeeren, die süß sind", too. All those are questionable constructions, but nothing unusual. Using *diejenigen* like that is as useless as an unspecific "es" (I hope you know what I mean). That is to say, it does serve its purpose, but it's rather colloquial. I'd consider it unlucky, not to say wrong, if a definite article, and *derjenige, diejenige* in this sense as well, should make a back-reference to a known entity--e.g. "Wir haben Erdbeeren gepflückt. Die Erdbeeren waren süß".

It is not all too different from a bare *diejenigen die*, as far as I understand. Compare:

> "Und dadrauf satteln diejenigen, die ...".

I wouldn't give one a preference over the other. English in comparison knows a strict proscription against dangling prepositions, though, as you might now, that is frequently disobeyed.

*diejenigen* would normally refer back, as I said, to a limited subselection: "Da sind vier Personen. Drei von denen tragen Hut. Ob **diejenigen** Haare haben, weiß ich nicht, doch die vierte Person hat eine Glatze." In a construction like this, *diejenigen* is actually necessary to disambiguate.

I think it's likely that the set phrase *diejenigen, die* developed to avoid a (phonetically unpleasent?) reduplication as in "Ich mag **die, die** süß sind."

*jenige* normally refers back to an already introduced entity, as I said: "Ich mag Erdbeeren. Vorallem **diejenigen, die** Süß sind." This can be transposed to the above example. This becomes obvious comparing

> "Ich mag (die) Erdbeeren. Vorallem die süßen."
>
> "Ich mag vorallem die süßen Erdbeeren"

Then generalizing:

> "Ich mag Erdbeeren. Die sind süß"

Finally relativizing:

> "Ich mag (nur) die Erdbeeren, die süß sind".